# Using Elementor to get dynamic content for wordpress on a predefined theme

Tags: content

Lets say i want to put posts on a page in an elementor page, but these posts should have a specific tag to show up here, I.E pulling posts dynamically from posts to a page according to a tag, or a condition, to do that with code would be easy, but how do i do that without coding, cuz im working with a downloaded theme, not my own.

Comment: That sounds a bit like a tag archive. Am I mistaken? If that's what you want, it's a built-in feature of WordPress. Where do you want to display those posts? On the homepage?

Comment: no, not a tag cloud, i want to put the posts with the tag "service", somewhere on the site

Comment: Yes, I wasn't talking about a tag cloud. WordPress automatically creates a number of archives, for example for authors and categories. They display all the content created by a particular author or under a certain category. The same works for tags. So, depending on where and how you want to display those posts, you could use the archive.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use the *Posts* widget. You can place it anywhere on your page, then use the *Query* control to determine what posts to include. For tags, pick *Include by > Term* and then include whichever tags you want to use under *Term*. Customize as needed.

[image]